# Can't match type in Haskell function

Tags: haskell

I have a function where I'm trying to input, for example:

```
look codeIndex 4719
```

Where codeIndex is a `Database` stored as `[(Int, String, Int)]`

The idea is that the function, given the index to draw from, and the code value, will return the tail of that element in the list (String, Int)

```
look :: Database -> BarCode -> BillItem
 look [] y = ("Unknown Item", 0)
 look (a,b,c:xs) y
       | y == a                = (b,c)
       | otherwise             = ("Unknown Item", 0)
```

I originally tried

```
look (x:xs) y
    | y == head x                = tail x
```

but that didn't work. I'm very new to Haskell and this is confusing me to no end!

Comment: Despite the title, this function is a *first-order* one (there are no functions being passed as arguments).

Comment: Understood; as I say, I'm new to haskell. My mistake, I will correct it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, though I think that the "original" approach you mention is probably a better idea, let's first get you pattern match error out of the way:

```
look :: Database -> BarCode -> BillItem
look [] y = ("Unknown Item", 0)
look ((a,b,c):xs) y
      | y == a                = (b,c)
      | otherwise             = ("Unknown Item", 0)
```

That is, when you said `(a,b,c:xs)`, what you were saying was the same as `(a,b,(c:xs))`. You don't want that, so you need the parens around `(a,b,c)`. Now, once that's fixed, it compiles!

But wait, it returns `("Unknown Item", 0)` for everything except the first thing in the database. It's as though you've told it to only look at the first thing, and if that doesn't match, return an error.

Oh wait, you have. Right there in your code, it says "if you have a non-empty database, check if it matches the first item and return that. Otherwise, return an error."

So let's fix that. If the first item doesn't match it should try the rest of the database, not return an error value.

```
look :: Database -> BarCode -> BillItem
look [] _ = ("Unknown Item", 0)
look ((a,b,c):xs) y
       | y == a                = (b,c)
       | otherwise             = look xs y
```

And in fact, that works:

```
type Database = [(Int, String, Int)]
type BillItem = (String, Int)
type BarCode = Int

look :: Database -> BarCode -> BillItem
look [] _ = ("Unknown Item", 0)
look ((a,b,c):xs) y
       | y == a                = (b,c)
       | otherwise             = look xs y

main = do
  let db = [(111, "Item One", 1),
            (222, "Item Two", 2),
            (333, "Item Three", 3),
            (444, "Item Four", 4),
            (555, "Item Five", 5),
            (666, "The Beast", 6),
            (777, "Item Seven", 7)]
  print $ look db 777
  print $ look db 111
  print $ look db 123
```

Comment: Quite possibly the most thorough answer I have ever received. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Precedence matters:

```
look (a,b,c:xs) y
```

The first argument above is a *triple*, made of `a`, `b`, and `c:xs`. The third component is a (non-empty) list.

```
look ((a,b,c):xs) y
```

The first argument above is a (non-empty) *list* of triples. Its first element triple is `(a,b,c)`.

For the future: remember to always post the type error when you get one -- it can greatly help answerers to spot what's going on.

Comment: @DanielMartin Absolutely! My answer only addresses one issue, the one mentioned in the title.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems; the pattern match pointed out by @chi, and you are mishandling the case where the *first* item doesn't match. You need to recurse so that you check *every* item in the list. Also, you should probably return a `Maybe BillItem` rather than a special value.

```
look :: Database -> BarCode -> Maybe BillItem
look [] y = Nothing
look ((a,b,c):xs) y
   | y == a                = Just (b,c)
   | otherwise             = look xs y
```